# Print array with specific conditions as below in java

Tags: java, arrays, reference, addition

Array Question - `int[] arr={1,2,3,4,5}`

First find out middle element of array

Addition 1st element of array to right side closest element of middle element i.e arr[0] + arr[3] = 1 + 4 = 5

Again add 2nd element of array to next right side element of middle element i.e. arr[1] + arr[4] = 2 + 5 = 7

Print this sums up to middle element after middle element array should print elements as a original array and get output as [5,7,3,4,5]

Note: get output elements and modify them as a original array elements so if we print original array i.e.

```
for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]); 
}
```

then output must be '5 7 3 4 5'

I tried this and I got output but how can I convert output in array elements and fill it to an empty array and refer to original array

```java
package javap;


public class Arraym {
    static void print (int arr[]) {
        int z = arr[arr.length / 2];

        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
       
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length/2; i++) {
            System.out.print(sum1= arr[i]+arr[i+z]) ;
        }
        for (int i = arr.length/2; i<arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(sum2=arr[i]);
        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[]= {1,2,3,4,5};
        print(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you ever considered `arr[i] = arr[i]+arr[i+z]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Java arrays are passed by reference. Thus, you can just modify it directly.

```java
public class Arraym {
    static void print (int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length/2; i++) {
            int z = arr[arr.length/2];
            int sum1=arr[i]+arr[i+z];
            System.out.print(sum1);
            // Write to each element of the array
            arr[i] = sum1;
        }
        
        for (int i = arr.length/2; i<arr.length; i++) {
              int sum2=arr[i];
              System.out.print(sum2);
              // No need to write to array, since it already contains the correct value.
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
        print(arr);
        
        System.out.println();
        for (int i : arr) {
            System.out.print(i); // prints 57345
        }
    }   
}
```

Note: I've made a couple of extra edits to the program:

1. In java, prefer `int[] variable` over `int variable[]`. They are the same, but the first is preferable as it better describes the type.
2. There is no need to declare all variables at the start of the function. Variables can be declared anywhere in a function and will only be visible within the declared block.
3. Always indent/format your code before posting.